# Where does outlook express or Firefox store certificates?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook, certificate

I've lost my Windows XP instance (something broke so that I couldn't run a single program after startup, so I switched to Linux).
I still have that partition, readable.

Now I need my StartSSL certificate.
I remember I imported it to Outlook Express and Firefox in PKCS12 format.
In which directory would I find the certificates on the disk?

Update: I have found
`/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Application Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxx.default/cert8.db`
So I copied the profile dir and opened in Firefox, but the certificate is not there.
So I have only Outlook left - I am 100% sure I imported the cert in.

Comment: Outlook Express uses the Windows certificate store, which stores things in `C:\Documents and Settings\*<Username>*\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto` and `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto` but that doesn't seem to be in an easily accessible format.

Comment: up vote 0 down vote accept
 
I found this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_cmuncertstor.mspx?mfr=true
So it seems I'd have to install windows in VirtualBox and restore keys through Windows tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox uses the NSS database, which consists of **`cert8.db`, `key3.db`, and `secmod.db`**. **All** of these files are needed to recover a certificate.